# Soap service method arguments error with AffiliateWindow's AffiliateService

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

I am in the process of implementing **AffiliateWindow's AffiliateService** (Soap) located **[here](http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v4/AffiliateService?wsdl)**.

I need to call only two methods from the this services. i have a project setup in VS 2010 and have added Web Servcie refrence and proxey class. Every thing is working fine except, the phase where i need to imput a TransactionId to get Transactions. it returen and error saying incorrect TransactionId.

on the other hand i can call the method (getTrasactionList) with dates and DateType. but when ever i try to pass TrasactionId or MerchantId to either methods, i get this error.

Exception detail also tell the Array to be empty. but im populating the array like this

`var gTrIdi = new getTransaction

{

 aTransactionIds = new ArrayOfint() { id = "'86862924'" }

};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.
the problem was with proxy class.

changed `private ArrayOfInt aTransactionIdsField;`
to `private int[] aTransactionIdsField;` in `getTransaction` class and it worked like a charm.